# how to get a search result from mysql in side bar on submit without refreshing page

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Can I can get a search result in a side bar without refreshing the page?

It is mainly the concept of hide and show the side bar showing the result, but it is not working exactly - the result is not showing in the side menu bar and I am not able to display it on side bar.

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js'></script>
<script>

$('#menu-button').click(function(){
     $('#hide-menu').toggleClass('show-menu');
});
</script>
<style>
body
    {
       overflow:hidden;
    }

.menu-button
    {
        border:1px solid #000;
        color:fff;
        display:inline-block;
        cursor:pointer;
    }

.hide-menu
{
    background-color:#336ca6;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(300px,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(300px,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(300px,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(300px,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(300px,0,0);      
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.show-menu      
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 }  
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<br>

<div style='display:none;'>
    <img src="images/loader.gif" />
</div>

<form action="" name = "form">  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="fn" Placeholder="Search Something..." style="width:300px; padding:8px;"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="menu-button"style="padding:8px;"/>
</form>
<br>

<div id = "s-results">
    <!-- Search results here! -->
</div>
<nav id="hide-menu" class="hide-menu">
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#s-results').load('search.php').show();


    $('#search-btn').click(function(){
        showValues();
    });

    $(function() {
        $('form').bind('submit',function(){
            showValues(); 
            return false; 
        });
    });

    function showValues() {
        $('#s-results').html('<img src="images/loader.gif" />');  

        $.post('search.php', { name: form.name.value },

        function(result){
            $('#s-results').html(result).show();
        });
    }

});
</script>

</center>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: help me put with piece of code

Comment: what code you have tried?

Comment: first try some code and then if you have any error then post here

Comment: The answer to your question is Yes, but, we aren't here to write all the code, only help out with things you're stuck with!

Comment: yes i have the piece of code that i had tried i am sharing it

Comment: now i had share a piece plze have a look on the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the preventdefault to stop submit the form, do this:

```
    $('form').bind('submit',function(e){
         e.preventDefault(); /* This will stop the submit of form */
        showValues(); 
        return false; 
    });
```